# Magento - slow url rewrite reindex

Tags: performance, magento, indexing

I'm thinking about improving reindexing of url rewrites in magento, we have 130k simple and configurable products. And reindexing consumes a lot of memory, basicaly I'm not able to finish this job in comammnd line because of memory limit.

So I started with looking for some solution which could speedup whole process. Whole reindex is happening in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url::_refreshProductRewrite` because system iterate over all products and categories and stores. And for each iteration it possibly does 1 or 2 `insertOnDuplicate` actions.

I'm thinking about storing such queries somewhere and merging them into one or more bigger queries which would be much more faster (I guess).

Slow bit for one comibation (product, category, store) looks like

```
    $this->getResource()->saveRewrite($rewriteData, $this->_rewrite);

    if ($this->getShouldSaveRewritesHistory($category->getStoreId())) {
        $this->_saveRewriteHistory($rewriteData, $this->_rewrite);
    }
```

Have anyone better idea how to improve this?

Answer (score 2):

I can't say that I've ever used the product (and I'm in no way affiliated), but it may be worth looking at [<strike>this module by EcomDev</strike>](http://shop.ecomdev.org/view-all/url-rewrite-indexer.html). It would seem from their [<strike>posted tests</strike>](http://www.ecomdev.org/2011/10/08/ecomdev-breaks-magento-speed-limits.html) that it's pretty nippy, and it would potentially save you a lot of work.

Comment: It introduces its own equivalents to core_url_rewrite table. I'm not sure if I replace core solution with their solution then I dont break anything in our app. I'm looking for something which just populates core_url_rewrite table in faster manner.

Comment: We've used the Ecomdev module on a site with a large number of products.  It improved indexing performance dramatically, and didn't break anything.  Ivan and the Ecomdev team do good work.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be really interesting. I did a workaround. The breaking part seemed to be transaction which is not really necessary in this case. So it's enough to call `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/url')->refreshRewrites();` from external php script, give it enough resources and time and it works fine. It's fast as normal magento indexing and it does its job for 150k products & 200 categories.

Comment: I can definitely recommend the module above, works like a charm.